# How to create a new module using ZFTool in ZendFramework?

Tags: zend-framework

I have downloaded and installed the XAMP and skeleton application of ZEND.
Now I am trying to create a new module using ZFTool using this command.

```
php vendor\bin\zf.php create module test
```

I get this message.

[image]

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should use zf.bat(in windows) instead of zf.php. Before you use the ZFTool, you must get into the directory you place your project,or you will fail to create the module by usintg the ZFtool.

ADD:
1.You do not need to get into the module directory, you just need to go into the zend-app directory;

2.You should ues "zf.bat"instead of "zf.bat.php";

3.I have do some testing in my Zend framework project,I could creat my module successfully。(Please look at the image below,assuming that I place my project in the directory ZF)

Commend Line:

I just use the command: D:\www\htdocs\ZF>zf.bat create module test

**I think you may use: 
D:\XAMP\zend-app\zf.bat create module test**

the result:

Creating the following module and artifacts:
D:\www\htdocs\ZF/application/modules/test/controllers
D:\www\htdocs\ZF/application/modules/test/models
D:\www\htdocs\ZF/application/modules/test/views
D:\www\htdocs\ZF/application/modules/test/views/scripts
D:\www\htdocs\ZF/application/modules/test/views/helpers
D:\www\htdocs\ZF/application/modules/test/views/filters
Added a key for path module directory to the application.i
Updating project profile 'D:\www\htdocs\ZF/.zfproject.xml'

Comment: Please check my above comment.

Comment: @Dixit Gokhale: I have update my answer, please check.

Comment: I don't have zf.bat I just have zf.php.bat

Answer (score 0):

The correct command to get your module created would be :

vendor\bin\zf.php.bat create module test

Comment: Just to add to my answer, please note that the above answer is for windows, but the command you wrote initially is for Linux or Mac